# ImageView to Bottom Right of Screen with Large ScrollView above it

Tags: android, android-layout

I am attempting to position an ImageView at the bottom right of the screen always. Behind it is a Vertical ScrollView that takes up the whole screen and will always be taller than a users screen. I am attempting to keep the ImageView always fixed to the bottom right of the screen not matter where on the ScrollVIew the user is.

My layout below does position the image correctly but it doesn't sit ontop of the ScrollView it sits below it (and crops off the bottom of the ScrollView). How can I get the scrollview to extend to the bottom of the screen and keep the ImageView exactly where it is no matter where the user scrolls?

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Is currently looks like this (note the black bottom chops off the ScrollView):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/groupname"
                android:paddingLeft="50px"
                android:textSize="35px"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="abc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="450dp" />
            <TextView
                android:paddingLeft="50px"
                android:textSize="35px"
                android:background="#FFFF00"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="abc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="450dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ImageView1"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groupname"
            android:paddingLeft="50px"
            android:textSize="35px"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="abc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp" />
        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="50px"
            android:textSize="35px"
            android:background="#FFFF00"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="abc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="450dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
     android:src="@drawable/camera" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it results in the same layout. I've tried making the background transparent already but the black if from the main relative layout. The problem is getting the imageview to sit ontop of the scrollview

Comment: If I am not wrong, you're getting black area around camera icon?

Comment: Yes its still black behind the camera icon (same black rectangle). The black is the RelativeLayout background

Comment: Check your app theme whether it is dark or what and then give color  like `white` to relative layout instead of `transparent`